# Is this a bug in std::gcd?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++17, unsigned, libstdc++

I've come across this behavior of `std::gcd` that I found unexpected:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>

int main()
{
    int      a = -120;
    unsigned b =  10;

    //both a and b are representable in type C
    using C = std::common_type<decltype(a), decltype(b)>::type;
    C ca = std::abs(a);
    C cb = b;
    std::cout << a << ' ' << ca << '\n';
    std::cout << b << ' ' << cb << '\n';

    //first one should equal second one, but doesn't
    std::cout << std::gcd(a, b) << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::gcd(std::abs(a), b) << std::endl;
}
```

*[Run on compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/PCL8Sg)*

According to [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/gcd) both calls to `std::gcd` should yield `10`, as all preconditions are satisfied.

In particular, it is only required that the *absolute values* of both operands are representable in their common type:

> If either |m| or |n| is not representable as a value of type `std::common_type_t<M, N>`, the behavior is undefined.

Yet the first call returns `2`.
Am I missing something here?
Both gcc and clang behave this way.

Comment: interestingly gcc compiles 2 ints to just print the value but an int and an unsigned doesn't: https://godbolt.org/z/koEVHh

Comment: What's `-120 % 10u`? (Hint: it's not 0.) Yes, bug.

Comment: @T.C. Yes, casting `-120` to `unsigned` will result in `4294967176` which `% 10u` is  `6`. My question was rather if this behavior is indeed incorrect, which it seems to be.

Comment: @AlanBirtles In that case, ther will be no cast to `unsigned`, so no bug either

Comment: Reported as https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=92978

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Looks like a bug in libstc++. If you add `-stdlib=libc++` to the CE command line, you'll get:

```
-120 120
10 10
10
10
```